# Spring Boot multiple WAR files in 1 Tomcat

Tags: spring-boot

we are developing a multi-mandator shop solution for multiple countries, like Sweden, Netherlands, Germany etc. We aim to have 1 WAR file for each mandator and would like to have all of them running in 1 tomcat. Is it possible to have this integrated into Spring-Boot's embedded tomcat?

Comment: Spring Boot's embedded tomcat uses one tomcat instance per application. If you want everything running in one tomcat why not go with traditional deployment?

Comment: @XtremeBiker Because we are aiming to use the embedded tomcat instead of an external one (runnable JAR file)

Comment: Then wrap the sources for each mandator in the same project. You'll have a runnable jar which launches all of them.

Comment: @XtremeBiker The source is the same for all mandators, we just need several instances of it in order to have a dedicated context for each mandator

Comment: Well, is only the language being changed for each of the mandators? Anyway, I don't see the reason of having different contexts if source is the same. Just make a configuration class which wraps the configuration for each of them.

Answer (score 2):

If the Mandators are different webapps/war files then you can add wars/web apps to the EmbeddedServletContainer(Tomcat), using the tomcat.addWebapp method.

In your spring-boot main class add the following bean.

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainerFactory() {
    return new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {

        @Override
        protected TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(
                Tomcat tomcat) {
            // Ensure that the webapps directory exists
            new File(tomcat.getServer().getCatalinaBase(), "webapps").mkdirs();

            try {
              Context context = tomcat.addWebapp("/Sweden","Sweden.war");
              tomcat.addWebapp("/Netherlands","Netherlands.war");
              tomcat.addWebapp("/Germany","Germany.war");                   
              context.setParentClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());
            } catch (ServletException ex) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to add webapp", ex);
            }
            return super.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(tomcat);
        }

    };
}
```